# RegExp for Javascript to get a substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to parse some plain text that I got from the Twitter API. What I need to do is basically search through a tweet to find a "@" character followed by some text and replace the plain text with an anchor linked to that text. For example:

Take the tweet plain text: "@flintzke this is a test"

and use a Regular expression to turn it into:

```
<a href='www.twitter.com/flintzke'>@flintzke</a> this is a test
```

my guess was to use this kind of function:

```
function getUsernameLink(text) {
var exp = /^[@][a-zA-Z0-9_!@#%&*]*[\s]$/ig;
return text.replace(exp, "<a href='https://twitter.com/$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

my objective was to find an expression that found a single word in a string, text, that starts with "@" and ends with a whitespace

Comment: just edited to show my current try

Comment: do you want the rest of the tweet placed into your result string?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have tried a bit to hard ;). Firstly the anchors `^` and `$` mark the beginning and end of the string (not the beginning and end of the match or something - which I suppose you assumed). Then you use `$1` but that corresponds to the first capture (the first set of parentheses - which you don't have). Either add parentheses around your match or use `$&`. And lastly, `\S` represents a non-whitespace character. So why not just match as many non-whitespace characters as possible?

```
exp = /@(\S*)/g;
return text.replace(exp, "<a href='https://twitter.com/$1'>@$1</a>");
```

Comment: ohh yes you are right I thought ^ and $ meant beginning of the matched string not the entire string. This looks much better! Is it possible to LOOK for the @ at the beginning of the word but not actually pull it into the $1? thanks alot

Comment: @MattHintzke sure. Make use of capturing ;). You are free to place the parentheses wherever you want. See my edit.

Comment: ohhh so the parenthesis is what indicates the actual "Capture" of the string? that is great! thanks

Comment: @MattHintzke yes, that's what I meant. Sorry if that was unclear. [Here is some further reading on the matter.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
text.replace(/\@(\w+)/g,"<a href='https://twitter.com/$1'>@$1</a>");
```

Comment: Not only that this will not work if the last word in the string is preceded by `@`, it will also remove the space between the linked word and the one after that.

Comment: Yup. Now only the first one still applies ;). It will still not work for a `@name` at the end of the string.

Comment: The below would satisfy your 1 st point but what @MattHintzke asked for was not to match a pattern at the end of the string.

`text.replace(/\@(\w+)/g,"<a href='https://twitter.com/$1'>@$1</a> ");`

Comment: His request was "What I need to do is basically search through a tweet to find a "@" character followed by some text and replace the plain text with an anchor linked to that text." He doesn't make any assumption about the position. I believe a solution should try to capture the OP's intent and not only work for the few specific examples he gives.

Comment: Then my last comment should satisfy his needs except that it will add a space at the end, if the pattern found at the end of the string.
Thanks

Comment: Since it will add an additional space in any case, just remove the space and the solution is fine ;)

Comment: any idea how to fix this one :
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654651/checking-for-a-string-which-contains-3-consecutive-letters-and-2-digits-in-any-o)

Comment: What does this mean `?=.*?`   ?

Comment: This is not the place to discuss this, and unfortunately you don't have enough reputation to enter a chat. But check out the link I posted in a comment to Kolink's answer. It explains the lookahead (which is what it is) very well. The whole tutorial on that website is definitely worth reading through, even if you have some understanding of regular expressions already.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to the website, are there rules that prohibits to chat with someone that does not have enough reputation ? 

Thanks

Comment: No, you can technically not enter a chat, because that requires a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat) your account does not have yet. But we can fix that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20420/discussion-between-m-buettner-and-mehdi-karamosly)