# Checking for a string which contains 3 consecutive letters and 2 digits in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one and thought I'd ask for some help here!

Basically I am validating a password field and the requirements are as follows:
- Must contain 3 consecutive letters
- Must contain at least 2 digits
- Can be in any order (e.g. 1abc342, abc24g3, 11abcsjf)

Here is what I have so far but I believe it needs some tweaking:
    /[a-z]{3}[0-9][0-9]/i

Comment: By "consecutive" do you mean three letters one after the other, or literally sequential like "MNO"?

Comment: They do not need to be sequential, just three in a row. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do this in two separate regular expressions: one to test for three consecutive letters and one to test for at least two digits:

```
/[a-z]{3}/i
/\d.*d/
```

Make sure both conditions are met. You could use lookahead to combine this into one regex, but I think two regexes is clearer code and a better solution.

But if I may inject some opinion on the matter: Unless you have no control over this (client specified this), I'd highly recommend not imposing password restrictions like this. They actually make your password system *far less* secure, not more secure. Some reading on why:

http://jimpravetz.com/blog/2011/06/cheap-gpus-are-rendering-strong-passwords-use/

http://jimpravetz.com/blog/2012/02/stupid-password-rules/

Comment: Thanks! This makes the most sense to me since I have no knowledge about lookaheads just yet. Also it is part of the requirements to have those restrictions and I totally agree with you. I assure you it's only used for educational purposes :)

Comment: Yeah, also what @m.buettner said =).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I've been creeping around on stackoverflow for quite some time now but never found the need to actually ask a question myself :) Great to be a member finally. You've got my checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

The regex you are describing can be written like so:

```
/(?=.*?[a-z]{3})(?=.*?\d.*?\d)/
```

The first lookahead searches for three letters in a row, in any position. The second lookahead looks for a digit in any position, followed by a digit further ahead.

Comment: For optimization purposes you should anchor this to the beginning of the string with `^`, I think.

Comment: I have limited knowledge about regex and I haven't learned how to use lookaheads yet. But I will come back and have a look at this sometime in the future. Thanks

Comment: @Arkayz without lookaheads validations like this may become very ugly in a single regex. [Here is some good reading on the topic.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) Of course, splitting up the validation into two steps like Ben does is probably the most readable and maintainable solution.